# Copiar un Directorio y pegarlo en una nueva direccion

Tags: vb.net

Que tal!

Estoy intentando copiar un directorio con archivos sea copiado y pegado en otra ruta, tengo esto.

```
    Dim Carpeta As String
    Carpeta = Path.Combine(SERVIDOR, DATA)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Carpeta)
    FileSystem.FileCopy("\27-22910\1", Carpeta)
```

El `FileSystem.FileCopy` es para un archivo, pero necesito copiar todo el directorio, alguien sabe de alguna funcion que podria utilizar ?

Comment: Y cual es el problema con FileSystem.CopyDirectory ?

Comment: La opción aquí es usar CopyDirectory para copiar todo el contenido del directorio fuente, aún si este contiene subfolders.

Comment: Muchas gracias, para copiar el directorio completo yo lo buscaba en la clase Directory y no encontraba alguna funcion para la copia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas copiar un directorio , puedes usar [**FileSystem.CopyDirectory()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127957(v=vs.110).aspx) para copiar todo el contenido de un directorio a otro.

```
 My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\Data\directorio_fuente", "C:\Data\directorio_destino", True)
```

- `directorio_destino` se crea si no existe.

incluso se puede usar con UNC :

```
 My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("\\server\directorio_fuente", "C:\Data\directorio_destino", True)
```